# Suitescript - translate internal ID to real name value

Tags: javascript, email, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am putting together an email alert. One of the fields in the email is the Sales Rep.

I am extracting from the record being created using the 'salesrep' field.

When I pass this to the email it is showing the internal id of the rep not the name.

What is the method by which this number can be displayed as a name rather than number?

variable repName is the sales rep.

Thank you in advance.

```
var repName = currentRecord.getValue ({
    fieldId:'salesrep'
});


body: "Details Below: <br>" +documentNum + "<br>" +repName
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use getText instead of getValue.
However in order to do this you have to reload the record you are creating.
Code below:

```
var objRecord = record.load({

type: record.Type.ESTIMATE,

id: recordId,

isDynamic: true,

});

var repName = objRecord.getText ({

fieldId:'salesrep'

});
```